# Problema no NodeJS Express Sessions: todas as informações estão sendo trocadas

Tags: node.js, session, login, express.js

Eu preciso de ajuda rápida ... Eu estou querendo saber por que meu aplicativo web (NodeJS 10.x) está dando esse erro estranho: Ele está trocando as sessões dos usuários... Quando um usuário edita seu perfil, as informações sempre vâo para o último usuário logado.

Exemplo Real:

- Usuário com e-mail **test001@teste.com** efetua login;
- Ele vai para a página de edição;
- Usuário com email **test003@teste.com** efetua login;
- usuário **test001@teste.com** modifica algo e salva;
- Os dados vão para o usuário **test003@teste.com**
- Às vezes ** incrivelmente ** a tela do usuário **test001@teste.com** PASSA A SER do usuário **test003@teste.com**!!

O sistema está atualmente desativado para manutenção.

Após a debugar, podemos ver que o problema é com a sessão: no controller de edição, aparentemente, o último ID de usuário registrado é usado para consultar o banco de dados.

Não sei se estou cometendo algum erro, ou é algum problema de configuração, mas agora temos cerca de 1000 usuários e toda a informação está sendo trocada, quando alguém edita o próprio perfil, as informações vão para outra pessoa ... Isso é muito SÉRIO.

Exemplo:

*route Candidatos*

```
router.post('/infoCurso', User.loggedIn, User.checkRoles(['usuario']), function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
        try {
            var success = await Candidato.infoCurso(fields)

            if (success) {
                res.status(200).send(true)
            } else {
                res.status(400).send(false)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    });
});
```

*controller Candidatos*

```
exports.infoCurso = function (data) {
    var cpf = req.session.passport.user.cpf

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var now = new Date()
        db.Curriculos.get(cpf, function (err, doc) {
            if (doc === undefined) {
                reject(false)
            }
            else {
                doc.cursos = JSON.parse(data.cursos_array)
                doc.dataAlteracao = dateFormat(now, "isoDateTime")
                db.Curriculos.insert(doc, doc.cpf, function (err, doc) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('UPDATE Curriculo')
                        console.log('Error inserting data\n' + err)
                        reject(false)
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(true)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

*app.js:*

```
var session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Seu código não aparenta ser funcional, afinal na função `infoCurso` não há referência alguma à variável `req` porém ela está sendo utilizada. E também tem que fazer o teste de máquinas diferentes ou pelo menos navegadores diferentes